# Method chain refactoring

Tags: java, methods, refactoring

I've got two static methods in a Java class :

```
public class MyFoo {
    public static ClassA foo(ParameterA pa, ParameterB pb, ParameterC c)
        // some implementation
    }
    public static ClassB bar(ParameterA pa, ParameterB pb, ParameterC c) {
        // some implementation
    }
}
```

And an implementation of ClassA with a method :

```
public class ClassA {
    public ClassB baz() {
        // some implementation
    }
}
```

Method `bar()` was introduced as a new feature and basically it replaces `MyFoo.foo(a, b, c).baz()`. I'd like to refactor such calls to `MyFoo.bar(a, b, c)`. Is it possible to do this in any IDE? I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, but tips for any IDE are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has [Structural search and replace](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/ssr.html) functionality, which allows me to reach my goal.

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans you can use the [Inspect and Transform functionality](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/editor-inspect-transform.html). You can write your custom script doing stuff like that. It can then be run on a set of files or by clicking a sidebar hint. See also [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/custom_declarative_hints_in_netbeans) and [this](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.cz/2012/05/creating-netbeans-custom-hint.html) blog entry.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the code which ever calls `bar()` - you can open every project in the universe which links against your code, then:

- Comment out the real `bar()` method
- Use your IDE's rename refactoring to rename `foo()` to `bar()`
- Delete the former `foo()` method
- Uncomment the real `bar()` method

Comment: But how does it get rid of the `baz()` call in `foo(..).baz()`?